# Java recursion and population growth model

Tags: java, recursion

In our Java class, we had to create a recursive method to calculate the end population.
I used the equation for the growth rate which is:
 = −1 + (1 − −1/)−1 where P is the population, r is the growth rate and K is max population.

The code below is my code. The code below that are the tests that need to pass.

My test will not pass, saying `expected <2080> but was <2100>`
When I use my calculator, the equation works correctly. Did I put something in the wrong order?

```
public static int calculateEndPopulation(int startPopulation, int maxPopulation, double growthFactor, int periods)
{
    if(periods == 0)
    {
        return startPopulation;
    }
    else
    {
        startPopulation = (int) (startPopulation + (startPopulation*(growthFactor*(1-(startPopulation/maxPopulation)))));
    }
   return calculateEndPopulation(startPopulation, maxPopulation, growthFactor, periods-1);
}
```

The tests that need to pass are below:

```
assertEquals(2000, Recursion.calculateEndPopulation(2000, 10000, 0.05, 0));
assertEquals(2080, Recursion.calculateEndPopulation(2000, 10000, 0.05, 1));
assertEquals(2162, Recursion.calculateEndPopulation(2000, 10000, 0.05, 2));
assertEquals(2246, Recursion.calculateEndPopulation(2000, 10000, 0.05, 3));
```

Comment: Shouldn’t the second return statement be in the else statement?

Comment: You are correct. I moved it back inside the else statement. (Didn't change the outcome obviously). Thank you!

Comment: You are dividing startPopulation by maxPopulation and they’re both ints which gives error. Just do a simple cast to a double of either maxPopulation or startPopulation

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that casting to `int` truncates the result, making it inaccurate. Using `double` instead produces the desired result.

```java
public static double calculateEndPopulation(double startPopulation, int maxPopulation, double growthFactor, int periods) {
    if (periods == 0) {
        return startPopulation;
    } else {
        startPopulation = (startPopulation + (startPopulation * (growthFactor * (1 - (startPopulation / maxPopulation)))));
    }
    return calculateEndPopulation(startPopulation, maxPopulation, growthFactor, periods - 1);
}
```

On a related note, when testing doubles for equality, you should use an epsilon (maximum acceptable absolute difference from actual value).

```java
//For example
assertEquals(2080, Recursion.calculateEndPopulation(2000, 10000, 0.05, 1), 1e-3);
```

Comment: Good answer! I think `maxPopulation` can be left as `int`.

Comment: @iota, quick question, as this works for the first test but the others fail (they are off by decimals). Is there any way to fix that, so that an integer is returned and not a double. I know that you added the epsilon on, but the tests come from my professor and he expects that the given tests pass.

Comment: @PresFelber `double` is not precise, so you need to use an epsilon. See the second part of my answer.

Comment: @PresFelber If you need it to be completely precise, then you can use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @PresFelber If you only compare integers, you could use Math.round.